# awk checking for multiple patterns in file

Tags: awk

Here's my code:

```
/usr/bin/gawk '{
!/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/ { a[".*Unauthorized.*Dup.*"] += gsub("(| ).*Unauthorized.*Duplication.*( |)", "&") }
!/simsX.ip/ { a[".*En_NoConn-.*"] += gsub("(| ).*En_NoConn-.*( |)", "&") }        
} END {
for (i in a)
printf("%s=%s\n", i, a[i])
}' /home/nagios/graphite-web_access.log
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
gawk: cmd. line:2:                                                                      !/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/ { a[".*Unauthorized.*Dup.*"] += gsub("(| ).*Unauthorized.*Duplication.*( |)", "&") }
gawk: cmd. line:2:                                                                                              ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:3: !/simsX.ip/ { a[".*En_NoConn-.*"] += gsub("(| ).*En_NoConn-.*( |)", "&") }   
gawk: cmd. line:3:             ^ syntax error
```

This code is suppose to search a file for the specified strings and then output results in the following format:

```
.*Unauthorized.*Dup.*=48
.*En_Conn-.*=0
```

I'm having issues identifying where the problem lies or how to fix it.  Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put a standalone condition inside an action part of the script instead of a condition part of the script.

Good:

```
awk '<condition> { <action> }'
```

Bad:

```
awk '{ <condition> { <action> } }`
```

You wrote:

```
awk '{   # <<<< NOTE!!!!
    !/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/ { a[".*Unauthorized.*Dup.*"] += gsub("(| ).*Unauthorized.*Duplication.*( |)", "&") }
    !/simsX.ip/ { a[".*En_NoConn-.*"] += gsub("(| ).*En_NoConn-.*( |)", "&")
}    # <<<< NOTE!!!
'
```

so your conditions (`!/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/` and `!/simsX.ip/`) are inside an action block (`{...}`). You probably meant to write:

```
awk '
    !/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/ { a[".*Unauthorized.*Dup.*"] += gsub("(| ).*Unauthorized.*Duplication.*( |)", "&") }
    !/simsX.ip/ { a[".*En_NoConn-.*"] += gsub("(| ).*En_NoConn-.*( |)", "&") }        
'
```

or less likely:

```
awk '{
    if (!/simsX.ip-17-31-28-19/) { a[".*Unauthorized.*Dup.*"] += gsub("(| ).*Unauthorized.*Duplication.*( |)", "&") }
    if (!/simsX.ip/) { a[".*En_NoConn-.*"] += gsub("(| ).*En_NoConn-.*( |)", "&")
}
'
```

Comment: i dont understand. please elaborate